# Extracting user id from token through a decorator

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm working on flask RESTful application that uses auth0 for authentication and authorization. Then, I wrote a decorator that validates the token and extract user's id from it. My goal is use that id, extracted from token, to used inside the decorated function, and throw an exception if user's id from token and from URL parameter doesn't match. This is aimed to avoid users to change data of another user, with his own token. I'm not sure this is the best practice for a RESTful app, but seems to be needed in my case.

That said, I trying to figure out the best approach pass the user's id from token, to the decorated funcion:

Something like this:

```
def authorization():
    def inner(func):

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                """
                token validation stuff
                ...
                """
                wrapper.user_id = token_payload['user_id']

            except Exception:
                return {"success": False}, 500

            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
    return inner


@authorization()
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def some_function():
    return jsonify({
        'success': True,
        'user_id': some_function.user_id
    })
```

As you can see, I setting the user_id field to the wrapper function, which seems to not be the best way, to do it. Is there any different approach to this situation? maybe using Flask resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can skip one level of wrapping in your decorator since you're not giving it any parameters.
2. Also, I'd just pass the extracted id into the wrapped function directly instead of setting an attribute.
3. And finally, you should add the auth decorater innermost, since the decorated function is what you want to register with Flask.
4. Extra: use `functools.wraps` to update the signature of your wrapped function, to make introspection and debugging easier.

Thus:

```
from functools import wraps

def authorized(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        try:
            # token stuff
            user_id = token_payload['user_id']
        except:
            return jsonify({"success": False}), 500
        return func(user_id, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
@authorized
def some_function(user_id):
    return jsonify({
        'success': True,
        'user_id': user_id
    })
```

Now every function you decorate with `@authorized` will need to have `user_id` as their first parameter, and everything should work as you expect.

Comment: Good point. My true decorator has parameters, and I considered to pass the id in the kwargs, happens that if I do this, every single function decorated gonna have to have **kwargs as parameter, even if I don't need that id that function.

Comment: @MatheusHernandes if you have some functions that need authorization but don't want the `user_id`, you could just make that a parameter of your decorator as well. Something like `@authorized(pass_id=True)` and then either call `func(user_id, ..)` or just `func(..)` depending on that.

Comment: could be... I'm between that alternative and one in the question

Comment: @MatheusHernandes If you want a more structured way to do this, you can use a `before_request` handler to handle your authorization stuff, and put the `user_id` into the `flask.g` app context namespace. You can then register a separate `Blueprint` for routes that need authorization which uses the `before_request` preprocessor.